# Carbon - OS X - Sending modified key events using CGEventPost

Tags: c, macos, events, keyboard, macos-carbon

I'm trying to programmatically send modified keystrokes, for instance a capital "A". The problem is that the shift modifier does not seem to have any effect.

In my code, I have two events, one for the shift key down, and another for the 'm' key down.

```
CGEventRef mDown = CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(NULL, (CGKeyCode)46, true);

CGEventRef shiftDown = CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(NULL, (CGKeyCode)56, true);

    CGEventPost(kCGAnnotatedSessionEventTap, shiftDown);
    CGEventPost(kCGAnnotatedSessionEventTap, mDown);}
    CFRelease(shiftDown);
    CFRelease(mDown);
```

The result is unfortunately always a small case 'm'!

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using CGEventKeyboardSetUnicodeString instead.  See [here](http://www.mail-archive.com/cocoa-dev@lists.apple.com/msg23343.html) for some sample code.

Comment: CGEventKeyboardSetUnicodeString() does not support adding modifiers like Ctrl to the event though.